# string as input to return only last character in Python, equivalent to lambda function

Tags: python, sorting

I have list of strings called nums. I am trying to write a  function called "last_char" that takes this list of strings as input, and returns only its last character. I want to use this function, last_char to sort my list called-"nums" by the last character/digit of each string, from highest to lowest, using sorted function in Python, where i will be using "last_char" function as my key.

I am able to do this with lambda function but I can't replicate this same thing with defined function. Below is my code with lambda function and unsuccessful code with defined function.

Please explain what is wrong with my code defined function code. Thank you for help.

```
'''working code using lambda function'''
nums = ['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16'] # this is input list to function, to get sorted based upon last character of each string
nums_sorted2 = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
print(nums_sorted2) # below is correct output
['19', '14378', '8907', '16', '1005', '44', '33', '32', '871', '1450'] # correct output as expected, using lambda function
```

Defined function - where I can't get the correct output

```
'''---Problem---'''
'''Defined function - where I can't get the correct output'''
nums = ['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16']  ## this is input list to function, to get sorted based upon last character of each string
lst=[]
def last_char(inp):
    for x in nums:
        lst.append(x[-1])
        lst.sort(reverse=True)
    return(lst)
print(last_char(nums))
#['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
nums_sorted = sorted(nums, key=last_char, reverse=False)
# incorrect output below 
#['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16']
# Desired/expected output
# ['19', '14378', '8907', '16', '1005', '44', '33', '32', '871', '1450']
```

Answer (score 1):

your last_char function should be a reflection of your lambda function, you are trying to do in your last_char the work of in-built function sorted but you should just give only the last char :

```
def last_char(inp):
    return inp[-1]

nums_sorted = sorted(nums, key=last_char, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
nums = ['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16'] 
num_tuples = [(num,int(num[-1])) for num in nums]
print([num_tuple[0] for num_tuple in sorted(num_tuples, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)])
```

Output:

['19', '14378', '8907', '16', '1005', '44', '33', '32', '871', '1450']

Answer (score 0):

So you were headed in the right direction of getting the last number and sorting based on that. Further, you can store the rest of the string - sorting still works, and then reproduce the original number afterwards.

```
nums = ['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16']  ## this is input list to function, to get sorted based upon last character of each string
lst=[]
def last_char(inp):
    for x in nums:
        lst.append((x[-1], x[1:])) # Store (last-number, rest) tuples
    lst.sort(reverse=True)

    outlist = []
    for x, i in lst:
        outlist.append(x + i)     # Append them back together
    return(outlist)
print(last_char(nums))
# ['19', '14378', '8907', '16', '1005', '44', '33', '32', '871', '1450']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function equivalent to a lambda expression is written like this.

```
nums = ['1450', '33', '871', '19', '14378', '32', '1005', '44', '8907', '16']

def last_char(inp):
    return inp[-1]
nums_sorted = sorted(nums, key=last_char, reverse=True)
print(nums_sorted)
#correct output 
#['19', '14378', '8907', '16', '1005', '44', '33', '32', '871', '1450']
```